# Set selected option of Country and State to USA

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im working on a registration where I have a dropdown list of Country and State.
My Problem is I don't know how to set the default country to USA and the states under USA.

I change the value of element.length and element.option and the selected index but its not working.

**SAMPLE**

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bdhacker/eRv2W/)

**CODE**

```
function populateStates(countryElementId, stateElementId) {

    var selectedCountryIndex = document.getElementById(countryElementId).selectedIndex;

    var stateElement = document.getElementById(stateElementId);

    stateElement.length = 0; // Fixed by Julian Woods
    stateElement.options[0] = new Option('Select State', '');
    stateElement.selectedIndex = 0;

    var state_arr = s_a[selectedCountryIndex].split("|");

    for (var i = 0; i < state_arr.length; i++) {
        stateElement.options[stateElement.length] = new Option(state_arr[i], state_arr[i]);
    }
}

function populateCountries(countryElementId, stateElementId) {
    // given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts <option> tags
    var countryElement = document.getElementById(countryElementId);
    countryElement.length = 0;
    countryElement.options[0] = new Option('Select Country', '-1');
    countryElement.selectedIndex = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < country_arr.length; i++) {
        countryElement.options[countryElement.length] = new Option(country_arr[i], country_arr[i]);
    }

    // Assigned all countries. Now assign event listener for the states.

    if (stateElementId) {
        countryElement.onchange = function () {
            populateStates(countryElementId, stateElementId);
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/qw75h3vz/

Check this:

```
function populateCountries(countryElementId, stateElementId) {
    // given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts <option> tags
    var countryElement = document.getElementById(countryElementId);
    countryElement.length = 0;
    countryElement.options[0] = new Option('Select Country', '-1');
    countryElement.selectedIndex = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < country_arr.length; i++) {
        countryElement.options[countryElement.length] = new Option(country_arr[i], country_arr[i]);
         if(country_arr[i]=="USA") {
            countryElement.selectedIndex=countryElement.length-1;
            populateStates(countryElementId, stateElementId);
         }
    }
```

Verify the if inside the for loop.

Comment: I updated my answer.  I missed a 1 on the if line.  I also included the working fiddle  : http://jsfiddle.net/Lw82jgtd/

Comment: It work sir, but the I need to display also the contents of state.. Ill try your code